# Angularjs: save base64 image from $scope in database/varbinary(max) - SQL Server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am having problem to save my imagem base64 in MSSQL database. I created a table TBEquipamento with a field FotoEquipamento varbinary(max);

I also created a web service using Web API 2:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/insertequipamento")]
[ResponseType(typeof(TBEquipamento))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> insertequipamento([FromBody] TBEquipamento addequipamento){

                objapi.TBEquipamento.Add(addequipamento);
                await objapi.SaveChangesAsync();

                return Ok("confirmationSuccess");
 }
```

I checked in my web service that my table field FotoEquipamento is varbinary(max) too. it's everything ok till here.

Now I my Angularjs, I have a picture in base64 like this example:

```
$scope.FotoEquipamento: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RDoRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7AAIAAAAKAAAISodpAAQAAAABAAAIVJydAAEAAAAUAAAQzOocAAcAAAgMAAAAPgAAAAA [...]
```

If I set the field $scope.FotoEquipamento to null like: **$scope.FotoEquipamento = null;** and pass all from Angularjs to WebService, it work perfectly. But when I pass my $scope.FotoEquipamento with a base64 data, it give me a error.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: "it give me a error."  ***What Error?***

Comment: I put a red point in the begging of my webservice, its possible to see that 
when I sent to it a base64, the object is null, but when I sent null to image, all is right. I guess the problem is that I am passing a base64 from angularjs to a filed varbinary(max) in my webservice, and I don't know how to convert that in Angularjs. Any ideia @Claies?

Comment: Without more information it's hard to say wether problem is on client or server side. To narrow down possible errors I'd recommend you: 1) show relevant angular  code 2) trace network traffic in browser network tab 3) set a breakpoint in your server routine

Comment: Perfect, but I guess the problem is that I have a value in base64 in angularjs and my POST in Web Service have a field varbinary(max), the error happen because the fields types is different. Do you know how can I convert my base64 image in angularjs to a hexa? I guess if I pass a hexa to this varbinary(max) field in webservice will work.

Comment: Claies, please tell me is its better now [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400016/image-base64-in-angularjs-to-c-sharp-varbinarymax).

Answer (score 0):

I did similar in angularjs, webapi environment and sql server. The difference to your implementation is that I just pass pure base64 encoded image without leading mimetype, coding information "data:image/jpeg;base64".
Snippet shows relevant code for preparing the binary data (image, ...) before saving it via webapi call.

```
 $scope.saveAttachment = function (content, filename) {
       // get empty default model record from database
       var newrecord;
       ...
       content = content.substr(content.indexOf("base64,") + "base64,".length);
       dataService.saveRecord(content_table, newrecord, 'id')
           .then(function (inserted) {
            newrecord["id"] = inserted["id"]; // get identity value from database insert ;
       });
  });
                }
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work:
I created a var base64img (my image base64 is in $scope.FotoEquipamento )
'var base64img = $scope.FotoEquipamento.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
                base64img = base64img.substr(base64img.indexOf("base64,") + "base64,".length);

                $scope.FotoEquipamento = base64img;'

It gave me:
console.log($scope.FotoEquipamento) = AQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RDoRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7 [..] and my web service is returning an error. In my MS SQL database all the images started like 00xxFFD8FF [...]

Comment: Karl, it didn't work, if possible give me more details in [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400016/image-base64-in-angularjs-to-c-sharp-varbinarymax).