# Image base64 in Angularjs to c# varbinary(max)

Tags: c#, angularjs, web-services

I have this class TBEquipamento in my webservice :

```
public partial class TBEquipamento
    {
        public int idEquipamento { get; set; }
        public int idTipoEquipamento { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idLocalidade { get; set; }
        public string NumSerie { get; set; }
        public string TAG { get; set; }
        public string Potencia_KVA { get; set; }
        public Nullable<float> TensaoPrimaria_V { get; set; }
        public Nullable<float> TensaoSecundaria_V { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idFabricante { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AnoFabricacao { get; set; }
        public Nullable<float> Volume_L { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idEqOperando { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idSistemaRefrigeracao { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idComutador { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idTipoOleo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> idSistemaPreservacao { get; set; }
        public byte[] FotoEquipamento { get; set; }
}
}
```

And this function to POST in it:

```
 // POST: função add equipamento    
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/insertequipamento")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(TBEquipamento))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> insertequipamento([FromBody] TBEquipamento addequipamento)
        {    

                objapi.TBEquipamento.Add(addequipamento);
                await objapi.SaveChangesAsync();

                return Ok("confirmationSuccess");

        }
```

The problem is when a pass a data to FotoEquipamento, I tried to pass a base64 and blob data to it from my Angularjs, but it doesn't work.

My image in angularjs is in my $scope.FotoEquipamento, and if I print it in console is: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RDoRXhpZgAATU0AKg [...]'

Do you guys have any ideia of how can a POST that image? Thank you all for the attetion.

Comment: please show your JavaScript code as well.

Comment: As already mentioned: 1) Show javascript code 2) give information what error you get on 2.1) Client side 2.2) Server side;